# Azure data warehouse load data from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, data-warehouse, price

I have the given scenario: I have some data on blob storage account and i want to load it into Azure Data Warehouse. I saw here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-load-with-polybase
```

that this is quite possible using Polybase. My question is whether there will be network traffic charge for loading data from Azure Blob Storage to Azure Data Warehouse or not. If so, let's say i have a 1TB flat file on premise. Uploading the file to Azure acording to this:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/
```

Is free right? (it seems that inbound traffic is free of charge and I pay only for the storage that I use monthly:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs-general/
```

So I will pay for 1 TB ZRS around 26 EUR / Month (storage)

If there will be network traffic charge between Azure Blob Storage and Azure Data Warehouse, I will have an additional charge acording to:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be charged for the network traffic when both the Blob Storage as the Data Warehouse are in the same region. However if it is not within the same region you will be chared. In the FAQ section on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/ you'll read:

> –Is data transfer between Azure services located within the same
> region charged?
> No. For example, an Azure SQL database in the same
> region will not have any additional data transfer costs.
>
> –Is data transfer between Azure services located in two regions charged?
> Yes. Outbound data transfer is charged at the normal rate and inbound data transfer is free.